# use static media files from server locally in django

Tags: python, django

Is it possible to use the static media files from a development server locally?

Instead of linking locally to localhost/static/media/some_pic.jpg I would like to link to use our development server dev.site.com/static/media/some_pic.jpg when I use relative urls in the templates.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the MEDIA_URL in your settings to 'http://dev.site.com/static/media/'.